# Send through office 365 account in salesforce

Tags: lightning, email, send-email, office-365, office-connect

Today suddenly one of our users is seeing this message in salesforce while sending emails.
Earlier it was working fine and he used to send email using office 365.

Our other users are not seeing this issue.
I'll ask him to connect again with office 365.

But anyone knows why this happened or is there a validity for 365 accounts let's say 6 months and after that, we need to validate again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this using Lightning Sync? [As documented in the release notes for Winter 21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353407&type=1&mode=1) it's being discontinued for new users in favour of using Einstein Activity Capture so it's possible the reconnection prompt is related to the recent update.

As far as I'm aware there isn't a timeout on the connection with Lightning Sync, I have only had to reconfirm the O365 connection when I have updated capture settings for EAC or changed the user's access settings.

There isn't any reference to it in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_enable_send_through_external.htm&type=5) either, except to note that users will be prompted on their first use of the send email action after configuration.

Comment: Einstein Activity Capture is only for new users. Also here I'm trying to send an email from salesforce as office 365